# How to get notification on Button Click?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I want notification on Button Click event in fragment.
I tried a a lot it is not giving me any error but its not showing me notification.

**main.java**

```
public class OneTimeTask extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    public OneTimeTask() {
    }

    ;

    String addtask, adddetail, adddate;
    static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;
    View view;
    EditText taskname, taskdetail, taskdate;
    Button taskadd;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    SessionManager session;
    JSONObject jsonobject;   
    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    private DatePickerDialog toDatePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;
    String uid;
    Intent intent;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_daily__task, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Task");
        taskname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.taskname);
        taskdetail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.taskdetail);
        taskdate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.taskdate);
        taskadd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.taskaddtask);

        GetCurrentGPSLocation gps = new GetCurrentGPSLocation(getActivity());
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

            // \n is for new line

        }else {
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        session = new SessionManager(getActivity());
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        uid = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_ID);
        setDateTimeField();



        return view;
    }
    private void setDateTimeField() {
        taskadd.setOnClickListener(this);

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                taskadd.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            }

        },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    }

    //  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == taskadd) {
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        }
        taskadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addtask=taskname.getText().toString();
                adddetail=taskdetail.getText().toString();
                adddate= taskdate.getText().toString();
                InsertData();
                Notification();

            }
        });
    }

    public void Notification() {
        // Set Notification Title
        String strtitle = getString(R.string.notificationtitle);
        // Set Notification Text
        String strtext = getString(R.string.notificationtext);

        // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
/*
         FragmentTransaction t = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                TabFragment mFrag = new TabFragment();
                t.replace(com.Weal.sachin.omcom.R.id.framelayout, mFrag);
                t.commit();
*/
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotificationView.class);
        // Send data to NotificationView Class
        intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);

        intent.putExtra("text", strtext);
        // Open NotificationView.java Activity
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //Create Notification using NotificationCompat.Builder
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
                // Set Icon
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                // Set Ticker Message
                .setTicker(getString(R.string.notificationticker))
                // Set Title
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notificationtitle))
                // Set Text
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.notificationtext))
                // Add an Action Button below Notification
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_audiotrack, "Action Button", pIntent)
                // Set PendingIntent into Notification
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                // Dismiss Notification
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Create Notification Manager

        // Create Notification Manager
        NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Build Notification with Notification Manager
        notificationmanager.notify(0, builder.build());

    }
```

Here my **noficationview.class**

```
        package com.Weal.sachin.omcom;

/**
 * Created by sachin on 1/23/2017.
 */

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class NotificationView extends Activity {
        String title;
        String text;
        TextView txttitle;
        TextView txttext;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.notificationview);

            // Create Notification Manager
            NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // Dismiss Notification
            notificationmanager.cancel(0);

            // Retrive the data from MainActivity.java
            Intent i = getIntent();

            title = i.getStringExtra("title");
            text = i.getStringExtra("text");

            // Locate the TextView
            txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
            txttext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

            // Set the data into TextView
            txttitle.setText(title);
            txttext.setText(text);
        }
    }
```

I tried this way and this code is not displaying the notification on Button Click...

Comment: does u get any error or what happens when u click ?

Comment: Firstly you should try to use a standard notification. After that you can replace it with the custom notification (which contains the custom view).

Comment: @W4R10CK nothings happen and no errors..

Comment: @Sachin, check the answer man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be that's because you are trying to add

```
taskadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addtask=taskname.getText().toString();
            adddetail=taskdetail.getText().toString();
            adddate= taskdate.getText().toString();
            InsertData();
            Notification();

        }
    });
```

inside onClick() of your fragment. Since you are already inside onClick() you will not be requiring taskadd.setOnClickListener().
Instead replace your onClick() method with this.

```
if(view == taskadd) {
    fromDatePickerDialog.show();
}
addtask=taskname.getText().toString();
adddetail=taskdetail.getText().toString();
adddate= taskdate.getText().toString();
InsertData();
Notification();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code to generate small and big notifications

full source code [source](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2014/05/implement-push-notification-in-your-app.html)

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PushNotificationDemo.class);
        final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification n;

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.nd_smallnotification:

                if (heading.getText().length() <= 0) {
                    heading.setError("Please provide push notification title");
                } else {
                    heading.setError(null);
                    heading_text = heading.getText().toString();
                    n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setContentTitle(heading_text)
                            .setContentText(message.getText().toString())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentIntent(pending)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_manage, "Close", pending)
                            .build();

                    n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP;
                    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
                }


                break;

            case R.id.nd_bignotification:

                if (heading.getText().length() <= 0) {
                    heading.setError("Please provide push notification title");
                } else {
                    heading.setError(null);
                    heading_text = heading.getText().toString();
                    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle nc =
                            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

                    nc.setBigContentTitle(heading_text);

                    String[] text = new String[5];

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        text[i] = i + ". say hello...";
                        nc.addLine(text[i]);
                    }

                    n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setStyle(nc)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentIntent(pending)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .build();

                    n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP;

                    notificationManager.notify(100, n);
                }

                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Init. your `onClick` inside `onCreate()`:

```
taskname = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.taskname);
taskdetail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.taskdetail);
taskdate = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.taskdate);
taskadd = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.taskaddtask);
taskadd.setOnClickListener(getActivity); //<----here
```

Use properly `onClick`, don't init. the view twice:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == taskadd) {
        fromDatePickerDialog.show();  //use this properly

        addtask=taskname.getText().toString();
        adddetail=taskdetail.getText().toString();
        adddate= taskdate.getText().toString();
        InsertData();
        Notification();

  }
}
```

Also to get the `context` of `fragment`. Remove `getContext()` from `Notification`:

Remove this:

```
getContext();
```

With this:

```
getActivity();
```